# Shall we start making our own collection of false cognates, and if so, where?

Tags: discusión, respuestas-wiki

I was just editing a [bilingual answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/2546/9385) and had to take out "censorship" and use "censure" instead.  ("Censure" is "criticism" but "censorship" refers to the suppression or prohibition of part of a book, letter, etc.)

I realized that *censorship* is a false cognate that might not be on the lists of faux amis.

Would it be fun and useful for us to gradually develop our own list of false cognates?

If so, would we do that in Meta or main?  What sort of structure?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend **community-wiki** question-answer (single answer) in the main site.

Meta is to discuss about the site itself and the main site is about the helpful content to learn Spanish.

At least for me, this would rank lower in the spectrum of "fun" than any other activities in the site. I don't see myself bringing new false cognates to that wiki answer when I see them.

About how useful it would be, well we have a counter of votes in every post. I just think that it would take *a lot* of time and effort for that post to be more useful than a quick google search for "false cognates in Spanish".